# Members of Dirent structure

Tags: c, linux, dir, readdir, dirent.h

I have started working with dirent.h library and I came across a very useful member of "struct dirent" structer which struct dirent *p->d_name in my book. But unfortunatly it doesn't states any other members of this structure;

I was wondering what else are the members of this structure and what are they used for?

Regards

Comment: I assume you're on Linux. In that case, simply read the dirent.h manual page (`man dirent.h`).

Comment: @NikosC. `No manual entry for dirent.h`

Comment: @Hi-Angel You're missing the POSIX man-pages package. (Whatever it's called in your Linux distro. On mine (Gentoo), it's sys-apps/man-pages-posix).

Comment: @NikosC. wow, I never knew that here's more than the default manual pages. Indeed, on my Kubuntu it was the package `manpages-posix-dev`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The structure, `struct dirent` refers to directory entry.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html

In linux it is defined as:

```
struct dirent {
    ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
    off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
    unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
    unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                   by all file system types */
    char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
};
```

refer: `man readdir`

Or just look for "dirent.h" in the include directory.

Comment: As written in another answer, only `d_ino` and `d_name` are [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). The rest should be avoided, or at worse used very cautiously, and only if you understand the implications.

Comment: The rest of the fields are needed just for extremely simple things (like determining if an entry refers to a file or a sub-directory), and telling people not to use any of the other fields is pointless (because they almost always must use them).

Answer (score 5):

There are only two members (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h)):

- `ino_t d_ino` - file serial number
- `char d_name[]` - name of entry (will not exceed a size of NAME_MAX)

Take a look at the [unix spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html) as well.

Comment: There might be some other (implementation or system specific) members, but you should not use them for POSIX portability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to above answer of @Binyamin Sharet:

```
 off_t d_off - file offset
    unsigned short int d_reclen - length of the dirent record
    unsigned short int d_namlen - length of name
    unsigned int d_type - type of file
```

Comment: These should not be used. They are implementation-specific and not defined by POSIX. You should probably update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: some filesystems (e.g. ext4, xfs) in some configurations (usually at mkfs time) can deliver the type of (some or all) the directory entries (the DT_* symbols). If not known, they are DT_UNKNOWN. The d_type member is not portable, but nevertheless widely available.