# Read all the image files within a directory using imread

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written following code, to read all the image files within a directory using imread. But the code is not working and giving error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
    string dirName = "/home/Dataset/newImage";
    DIR *dir;
    dir = opendir(dirName.c_str());
    string imgName;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if (dir != NULL) {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
             imgName= ent->d_name;
            Mat img = imread(imgName);
            cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } else {
        cout<<"not present"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    OOpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 2834
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:2834: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I actually forgot to add line "imgName = ent->d_name" in previous code. Sorry for that. I have updated the code

Comment: You never set `imgName` to anything in this code. The result is an invalid file name (none), which results in a `cv::Exception` thrown, not handled by your code, so the process terminates.

Answer (score 4):

This is failing because imread is only getting a file name, not a full path. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991334/members-of-dirent-structure).

```
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
         imgName= ent->d_name;
        Mat img = imread(imgName);
        cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
```

Should be something like

```
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        string imgPath(dirName + ent->d_name);
        Mat img = imread(imgPath);
        cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
```

I am not familiar with dirent, as I prefer boost::filesystem for this kind of thing.  Btw, I bet some "printf debugging" would be helpful here, to look at the arguments to 'imread' that lead to failure.

**EDIT:**

It looks like OpenCV's `imread` has some known issues, depending on how your program is built.  Is your system Windows, or something else?

See these links for more information:

[imread not working in Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417637/imread-not-working-in-opencv)

[OpenCV imread(filename) fails in debug mode when using release libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125817/opencv-imreadfilename-fails-in-debug-mode-when-using-release-libraries)

To troubleshoot this, perhaps you can try using the C interface, and in particular `cvLoadImage`.

Comment: Still not able to load the image. On using printf on imgPath, I am getting correct output - /home/Dataset/NewImage/17003.jpg. But img.empty() is turning out to be true.

Answer (score 3):

I did this with your code... maybe it can help you (Sorry, this is my first answer and I don't know how to make the code to look good)

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
 #include<dirent.h>
 #include<string.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 int main()
 {
     string dirName = "/home/diego/Pictures/";
     DIR *dir;
     dir = opendir(dirName.c_str());
     string imgName;
     struct dirent *ent;
     if (dir != NULL) {
     while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
           imgName= ent->d_name;
           //I found some . and .. files here so I reject them.
           if(imgName.compare(".")!= 0 && imgName.compare("..")!= 0)
           {
             string aux;
             aux.append(dirName);
             aux.append(imgName);
             cout << aux << endl;
             Mat image= imread(aux);
             imshow(aux,image);
             waitKey(0);
           }
      }
      closedir (dir);
  } else {
      cout<<"not present"<<endl;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line and make sure your `imread` is successful.

```
Mat img = imread(imgName);
if(img.empty()){
std::cout<<"Cannot load "<<imgName<<endl;
return -1;
}
```

In the above code you are getting such an error because, you are trying to convert empty Mat to gray scale, which will throw such an exception, so always make sure the Mat is not empty after `imread`.

Comment: I had added the code but I am getting "cannot load", even though I had added imgName in it.